# Internationalize in spring mvc/java. Translating only first line of messages.property

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I got next problem with my application. I want to internationalize my pages. On first page I have problem, because app translate only first variable. Firstly i added messages_en.properties in src/main/resources.

```html
addGame.form.gameId.label =  Game ID
addGame.form.gameName.label = Game name
addGame.form.gamePlatform.label = Game platform
addGame.form.gamePrice.label = Game price
addGame.form.gameDescription.label = Game description
addGame.form.gameCategory.label = Game category
addGame.form.gamesInStock.label = Games in stock
addGame.form.condition.label = Game condition
addGame.form.gameImage.label = Game image
```

Next step was add choice of language in addGame.jsp. It's work good.

```html
<div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:50px">
<a href="?language=pl" >polski</a>|<a href="?language=en">angielski</a>
</div>
```

Next step in DispatcherServlet-context.xml added one bean.

```html
<bean id="localeResolver"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
<property name="defaultLocale" value="pl"/>
</bean>
```

And in same file

```html
<mvc:interceptors>
<bean class= "org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
<property name="paramName" value="language"/>
</bean>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

And last what i do was added language to GameController like this.

```html
 @InitBinder
 public void initialiseBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
 binder.setDisallowedFields("unitsInOrder", "discontinued");
 binder.setAllowedFields("gameId", "gameName", "gamePrice", "gameDescription","gamePlatform", "gameCategory", "gamesInStock", "gameImage", "language");
 }
```

[Screen from page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQLP3.png)

On screenshot you can see my page after click English language. its changing only first variable. Could you tell me why?

Mine code. You can see messages_en.properties up. This is DispatcherServlet-context.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
 <mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"
  validator="validator" />
 <context:annotation-config />
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resource/**" location="/resources/" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.kk.gamestore" />

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="multipartResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
  <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10240000" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="messageSource"
  class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
  <property name="basename" value="messages" />
 </bean>

 <bean
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
  <property name="mediaTypes">
   <map>
    <entry key="json" value="application/json;charset=UTF-8" />
    <entry key="xml" value="application/xml;charset=UTF-8" />
    <entry key="html" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
   </map>
  </property>
  <property name="defaultViews">
   <list>
    <ref bean="jsonView" />
    <ref bean="xmlView" />
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

 <bean id="jsonView"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
  <property name="prettyPrint" value="true" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="xmlView"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
  <constructor-arg>
   <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
    <property name="classesToBeBound">
     <list>
      <value>com.kk.gamestore.domain.Game</value>
     </list>
    </property>
   </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
 <bean id="validator"
  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
  <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource" />
 </bean>
 <bean id="localeResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
  <property name="defaultLocale" value="pl" />
 </bean>
 <mvc:interceptors>
  <bean class="com.kk.gamestore.interceptor.PerformanceMonitorInterceptor" />
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
  <property value="language" name="paramName"/>
  </bean>

  <bean class="com.kk.gamestore.interceptor.AuditingInterceptor" />
  <bean class="com.kk.gamestore.interceptor.PromoCodeInterceptor">
   <property name="promoCode" value="PROMOGRY" />
   <property name="errorRedirect" value="invalidPromoCode" />
   <property name="offerRedirect" value="games" />
  </bean>
 </mvc:interceptors>

</beans>
```

There is GameController. I added position language in method - setAllowedFields

```html
 package com.kk.gamestore.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.MatrixVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.kk.gamestore.domain.Game;
import com.kk.gamestore.exception.GameNotFoundException;
import com.kk.gamestore.service.GameService;

@RequestMapping("/games")
@Controller
public class GameController {

 @Autowired
 private GameService gameService;

 @RequestMapping
 public String Welcome(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getAllGames());
  return "games";
 }

 @RequestMapping("/all")
 public String allGames(Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getAllGames());
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/{platform}")
 public String getGamesByPlatform(Model model, @PathVariable("platform") String gamePlatform) {
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getGamesByPlatform(gamePlatform));
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/filter/{ByCriteria}")
 public String getGamesByFilter(@MatrixVariable(pathVar="ByCriteria")
 Map<String,List<String>> filterParams, Model model){
  model.addAttribute("games", gameService.getGamesByFilter(filterParams));
  return "games";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping("/game")
 public String getGamesById(@RequestParam("id") String gameId, Model model){
  Game game = gameService.getGameById(gameId);
  model.addAttribute("game", game); 
  return "game";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String getAddNewGameForm(Model model) {
 Game newGame = new Game();
 model.addAttribute("newGame", newGame);
 return "addGame";
 }
 
 @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String processAddNewGameForm(@ModelAttribute("newGame") @Valid Game gameToBeAdded, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {
  if(result.hasErrors()) {
   return "addGame";
   }
  String[] suppressedFields = result.getSuppressedFields();
  if (suppressedFields.length > 0) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Próba wiązania niedozwolonych pól: " + StringUtils.arrayToCommaDelimitedString(suppressedFields));
  }
  MultipartFile gameImage = gameToBeAdded.getGameImage();
  String rootDirectory = request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
  if (gameImage!=null && !gameImage.isEmpty()) {
  try {
  gameImage.transferTo(new File(rootDirectory+"resources\\images\\"+gameToBeAdded.getGameId() + ".png"));
  } catch (Exception e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Blad podczas zapisu okladki gry.", e);
  }
  }
 gameService.addGame(gameToBeAdded);
 return "redirect:/games";
 }
 
 @InitBinder
 public void initialiseBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
 
 binder.setAllowedFields("gameId", "gameName", "gamePrice", "gameDescription","gamePlatform", "gameCategory", "gamesInStock", "gameImage", "condition" , "language");
 } 
 
 
 @ExceptionHandler(GameNotFoundException.class)
 public ModelAndView handleError(HttpServletRequest req, GameNotFoundException exception) {
 ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
 mav.addObject("invalidGameId", exception.getGameId());
 mav.addObject("exception", exception);
 mav.addObject("url", req.getRequestURL()+"?"+req.getQueryString());
 mav.setViewName("gameNotFound");
 return mav;
 }


 @RequestMapping("/invalidPromoCode")
 public String invalidPromoCode() {
 return "invalidPromoCode";
 }
}
```

And AddGame.jsp

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>Gry</title>
</head>
<body>
 <section>
  <div class="jumbotron">
   <div class="container">
    <h1>Gry</h1>
    <p>Dodaj gry</p>
       </div>
   <a href="<c:url value="/j_spring_security_logout" />" class="btn btn-danger btn-mini pull-right">wyloguj</a> 
   <div class="pull-right" style="padding-right:50px">
    <a href="?language=pl" >polski</a>|<a href="?language=en" >angielski</a>     
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="container">
  <form:form modelAttribute="newGame" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="alert alert-danger" element="div"/>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Dodaj nową grę</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-2" for="gameId">
     <spring:message code="addGame.form.gameId.label"/>
     </label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:input id="gameId" path="gameId" type="text" class="form:input-large" />
      <form:errors path="gameId" cssClass="text-danger"/>
     </div>
     
    </div>  
    
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-2" for="gameName">Nazwa</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:input id="gameName" path="gameName" type="text" class="form:input-large" />
      <form:errors path="gameName" cssClass="text-danger"/>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-2" for="gamePrice">Cena</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">  
      <form:input id="gamePrice" path="gamePrice" type="text" class="form:input-large" />
      <form:errors path="gamePrice" cssClass="text-danger"/>
     </div>
    </div>
    
     <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="gamePlatform">Platforma Gry</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:radiobutton path="gamePlatform" value="PS4" />
      Playstation 4
      <form:radiobutton path="gamePlatform" value="XBOX ONE" />
      Xbox One
      <form:radiobutton path="gamePlatform" value="PS3" />
      Playstation 3
      <form:radiobutton path="gamePlatform" value="XBOX 360" />
      Xbox 360
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-2" for="gameCategory">Kategoria</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:input id="gameCategory" path="gameCategory" type="text" class="form:input-large" />
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2 col-lg-2" for="gamesInStock">Liczba gier w magazynie</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">  
     <form:input id="gamesInStock" path="gamesInStock" type="text" class="form:input-large" />
     </div>
    </div> 
    
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="gameDescription">Opis</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:textarea id="gameDescription" path="gameDescription" rows="2"/>
     </div>
    </div>
   
    <div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="condition">Stan</label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
      <form:radiobutton path="condition" value="New" />
      Nowy
      <form:radiobutton path="condition" value="Old" />
      Używany
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-lg-2" for="gameImage">
    <spring:message code="addProdcut.form.gameImage.label"/>
    </label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
    <form:input id="gameImage" path="gameImage" type="file" class="form:input-large" />
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
      <input type="submit" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary" value="Dodaj" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </fieldset>
  </form:form>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

I haven't idea what i doing wrong. Button of changing language working well, but it's translate only first variable no more. On screen you can see en version (not default) and it changed only first variable and next variable name its from default lang. I haven't problems in console when running application just one warning like this.

> WARNING: [SetContextPropertiesRule]{Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:gamestoreCOPIED' did not find a matching property.

@EDIT:
Hi, after few days coding and repairing errors im back there. I got new informations.

PROBLEM : Application working good.
Locale change button working good. After click on this button application generate link (if english button click: http://localhost:8080/gamestore/games/add?language=en or if polish: add?language=pl)
and language are changing.
When i want change it on english language it translate me only first word of messages_en.properties. When i make english language default - its same situation - only first word its changing.
In console 0 errors only one warning but its nothing in this topic.
Problem is when i try change language on english or use on default english its change only first line of messages_en.properties.

If i change ResourceBundleMessageSource for ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource(with changing classpath and make it good)
nothing changed.

```html
<bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

I need this line.

```
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true"
```

So i can't make mine app with HandlerMapping. But if i do it its not working.

I read a lot of informations and trying find answer in network but nothing work. Anyone got similiar problems in past?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I just read it. Sorry for words like help me ASAP, but i just added mine code to post and refreshed post, to make bigger visibility. Now someone can see my real code and maybe help me. But in future i will not use sentences like this